# Определить, пустой ли файл в php-скрипте

Tags: файлы, php

Здравствуйте. Разбираюсь в премудростях работы с файлами в php. В процессе наткнулся на такую проблему: открываю файл через fopen, записываю через fwrite, считываю как строки с помощью fgets и вывожу все на экран. Все прекрасно работает. Но наткнулся на проблему, когда нужно проверить, есть ли что-то в файле (заказы, например) и, в случае, если в файле нет строк-заказов - вывести надпись "Заказов нет", иначе вывести на экран содержимое. Думал, все просто, оказалось, что для меня не все настолько очевидное. Помогите, пожалуйста, удовлетворить любопытство. Спасибо.

Код:

```
<?php
//открываем файл для записи (если его нет - создается автоматически
@$fp = fopen("$DOCUMENT_ROOT/../vovan/orders/orders.txt", 'r');
if (!$fp) {
    echo "<p><strong>Какие-то проблемы с файлом? А если найду?<strong></p>";
    exit;
}

while (!feof($fp)) {
    $order = fgets($fp, 999);
    echo $order . "<br /><br />";
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: Кстати, понимаю, что можно запихать все строки в массив, потом проверять его на пустоту. Но мне бы хотелось узнать, как решить вопрос в случае описанном выше.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

//определяем константу для имени файла
define('FILENAME', 'orders.log');

// проверяем наличие содержимого в файле, считывая содержимое файла в строку
if (!file_get_contents(FILENAME))
         echo "Заказов нет!";
else{
    // заказы существуют, обрабатываем их
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте!
Чтобы проверить пустой файл или нет можно воспользоваться функцией **filesize($file_name)** - она вернет 0 если файл пустой.
Если надо найти в файле определенную строку, тогда уже считывайте и сравнивайте с эталоном. Было бы хорошо если файл будет иметь некую структуру облегчающую нам поиск нужного содержимого. Там глядишь и регулярку можно составить:

```
(preg_match('наше регулярное выражение', file_get_contents($file_name), $resultat))
```

как - то так примерно.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, лучше проверять `filesize()`, но если нужно просто расковырять функции работы с файлами, то вот что могу сказать:

```
file_put_contents('test.txt', '');                 // case 1
//file_put_contents('test.txt', '1');              // case 2
//file_put_contents('test.txt', '12'.chr(0).'34'); // case 3

$fp = fopen('test.txt', 'r');

fseek($fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
$i = 0;
while ($i < 1000)    // защитимся на всякий случай
    {
    if (feof($fp))
        {
        echo 'empty';
        break;
        } else
        {
        echo 'NOT empty: '.ord(fread($fp, 1));
        }

    echo '<br>';
    $i++;
    }
```

Проверяя разные варианты первых 3-х строк, увидишь, что в конце любого (даже пустого) файла всегда стоит 0. То есть, чтобы прямо при с помощью `feof()` увидеть, не является ли начало — концом, нужно прочесть 1 байт (), а потом проверить feof.

*Не уверен, что наличие этого нулбита не зависит от ФС или ОС.*